# Is it possible to call another xslt transformation from within XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, reverse

I have asked a question [XSLT: how to reverse the tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727860/xslt-how-to-reverse-the-tree) and it was answered.

Now I have `transform1.xsl` which generates some XML output. I would like to reverse the output of `transform1.xsl` in `reverse.xsl`. I do not like to change the functionality of `transform1.xsl` because it is used elsewhere.

Is it possible to call `transform1.xsl` from within `reverse.xsl`and then reverse the output of it?

I tried the following code of `reverse.xsl`, but it reversed only untouched nodes:

```
  <xsl:include href="transform1.xsl" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
        <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="descending" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

I prepared a simplified example.
Input XML file:

```
<root>
   <child1/>
   <child2/>
</root>
```

`transform1.xsl', which I would not like to change:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="child2" >
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        <child3>
          <grandchild1 />
          <grandchild2 />
        </child3>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output of reverse.xml:

```
<root>
   <child3>
      <grandchild2 />
      <grandchild1 />
   </child3>
   <child2 />
   <child1 />
</root>
```

Comment: I don't think I understand. You'd like to reverse a tree twice?

Comment: I don't understand your question either. In XSLT 1.0 a transformation can have only one output (unless your processor supports an extension).

Comment: @MathiasMüller, No I would like to reverse it once. 'transform1.xsl` is another transformation, not reversing.

Comment: Then, why not have two entirely separate transformations? First transform the original source XML with `transform1.xsl` and then transform the intermediate output with `reverse.xml`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, May be the answer is that it is impossible. Instead of processing of an input XML file I wanted `reverse.xsl` to call `transform1.xsl` and reverse the output of  `transform1.xsl`

Comment: @Michael, I updated the question with an example

Comment: @MathiasMüller, I did not want to have two separate transformations, because I have an infrastructure which executes my xsl files with specific names and I did not want to complicate the infrastructure. I did not describe all the details because I wanted to simplify the question.

Comment: It's still difficult to understand what you're after. A stylesheet cannot call another stylesheet to pre-process the input or post-process the output. You can, however, apply/call templates from another stylesheet using xsl:import and xsl:include.